# I am getting the error NoReverseMatch inspite of including the url name in urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am getting the following error inspite of including the url name in urls.py:

```
Reverse for 'upload' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

I have given the url name as 'upload' in urls.py
initially home.html is supposed to post to 'upload' which is the FileView which i have included as:

```
url(r'^upload/',FileView.as_view(),name='upload')
```

**views.py**

```
def initial(request):
    return render(request,'display/home.html')

class FileView(FormView):
    template_name = 'display/upload.html'
    form_class = FileForm
    success_url = 'success/'


    def form_valid(self, form):
    file_upload = FileModel(
    fileup=self.get_form_kwargs().get('files')['fileup'])

    #results = FileForm.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=your_search_query)     | Q(startdate__icontains=your_search_query) |   Q(enddate__icontains=your_search_query)).order_by('pub_date')

     file_upload.save()
    self.id = file_upload.id
    return render_to_response('display/success.html')
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('file_upload', kwargs={'pk': self.id})

def redirect(request):
    return render(request,"display/success.html")
...
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

from display.views import FileView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^start/', views.initial,name='home'),
    url(r'^upload/',FileView.as_view(),name='upload'),
    url(r'^success/',views.redirect,name='success'),
    #url(r'^upload',views.upload,name='upload'),
    ]
```

**templates
home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CSV FILE UPLOAD</title>
    </head>

<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="{% url 'upload' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}



        <input type="submit" name="submit"  />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Is this the `urls.py` for your project or an app?

Comment: update with full traceback please

Comment: its for the app @Selcuk .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `urls.py` doesn't look like a root url conf... maybe a include inside your root url conf is missing?

Example:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^display/', include('display.urls', namespace='display')),
]
```

If it's included like this, you should refer to the `upload` url as:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="{% url 'display:upload' %}">
```

Other possible solution, try adding `$` in the end of your url regex:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

from display.views import FileView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^start/$', views.initial,name='home'),
    url(r'^upload/$',FileView.as_view(),name='upload'),
    url(r'^success/$',views.redirect,name='success'),
]
```